# how to store string in date in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

how to store string value in date variable in vb.net

i am using the following code

```
dim dtBL as Date
txtBLDate.text="23/11/2010"
dtBL = Format(CDate(txtBLDate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

but i am getting the error which says that 'Conversion from string "23/11/2010" to type 'Date' is not valid.'
please advice on this

Answer (score 3):

Two rules of thumb I give everyone with VB.Net:

- Turn Option Strict On
- Abandon the `Microsoft.VisualBasic`-Namespace ASAP

To answer your question, your date is in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and not `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Why abandon the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace?  It is part of VB and won't go away.  Definitely abandon the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility namespaces, however.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway: Because importing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` will also import the 'legacy' VB6-Functions which will show up in AutoCompletion. Importing and especially using `Microsoft.VisualBasic` will turn VB.NET into an ugly hybrid of Object-Oriented and Functional language features and defeats IMO the whole purpose of VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

i am using vb.net in web applications

i put a page code that may be helping you dealing with dates

---

ASPX

---

[image]

---

code behind

---

```
Partial Class DateFormatConversions Inherits System.Web.UI.Page Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lblDate.Text = Today.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    lblDate.Text = Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
End Sub 
Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    lblDate.Text = Today.ToString("d/M/yyyy")
End Sub

Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    lblDate.Text = Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
End Sub

Protected Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim DTFI As New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
    DTFI.ShortDatePattern = DropDownList1.SelectedValue

    Dim addedDate As DateTime
    addedDate = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text, DTFI)

    lblDateOutput.Text = addedDate.ToLongDateString
End Sub End Class
```

Comment: Can you please fix the wording formatting of your post, it's hardly readable. Thanks.

Comment: i am also adding a function that i use in date conversion, i put it as another answer, check it if you can get some ideas from it. sorry again for "jammed" posts

Comment: thanks mokokamello for your comment i have solved the issue by using the code below                           Dim BLMonth, BLDay, BLYear As String
 Dim dtBL As Date
 BLDay = strBLDate.Substring(0, InStr(strBLDate, "/") - 1)
            BLMonth = strBLDate.Substring(InStr(strBLDate, "/"), 3)
            BLYear = strBLDate.Substring(InStrRev(strBLDate, "/"))
            dtBL = CDate(BLMonth & "/" & BLDay & "/" & BLYear & "")

Comment: press space bar 4 times will tell the editor that code is coming. for example: spaceX4 then type "dim i as integer"

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic  Imports System.Globalization  Public Class DatumKonvert1 Public Shared Function DK1(ByVal myDMstring As String) As Date 
Dim source As String = myDMstring 
Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "d'/'M'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
Dim resultMydate As String = d.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy") 
Dim mdx = DateTime.ParseExact(resultMydate, "M'/'d'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
Return mdx     End Function End Class
```